# Integer Pointer Subtraction

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I've written a few lines of code predominantly from a book that gets you to declare an `integer` array, then subtract and pass two `addresses` from the array to another `integer`, in order to pass into a `printf` statement.  I'm not sure why, but my actual pointers: `aPointer` and `bPointer` seem to be `8 bytes`, which poses a problem when I try and pass the subtracted `addresses` to an `integer`.

I then changed the latter to a `long`.  The errors are not present in Xcode now, but I cannot print the address of `pointerSubtraction` properly using the `%p` specifier which does indeed expect an `int` and not a `long`.

```
    int arrayOfInts[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                arrayOfInts[i] = i;
                printf("%d", arrayOfInts[i]);
                // prints out 0123456789
            }

            printf("\n");

            int *aPointer = &arrayOfInts[1];  // get address of index 1
            int *bPointer = &arrayOfInts[7];  // get address of index 7
            long pointerSubtraction = bPointer - aPointer;  // subtract index 7 with 1

            printf("The size of aPointer is %zu bytes \n", sizeof(aPointer));
            printf("The size of aPointer is %zu bytes \n", sizeof(bPointer));
            printf("The address of aPointer is %p \n", aPointer);
            printf("The address of bPointer is %p \n", bPointer);
            printf("The address of final is %p \n", pointerSubtraction);
            printf("The value of pointerSubtraction is %ld \n \n", pointerSubtraction);
```

Comment: `pointerSubtraction` is not an address.  Think about it...what address would `&arrayOfInts[7] - &arrayOfInts[1]` possibly represent?

Comment: "the `%p` specifier which does indeed expect an `int` and not a `long`." -- ***WRONG!*** It expects a `void *`. Passing anything else to it results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to use a variable typed `ptrdiff_t` to store the difference of two pointer values, two addresses.

To `printf()` out a `ptrdiff_t` use the length modifier `"t"`. As `ptrdiff_t` is a signed integer use the conversion specifier `"d"`.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int a = 0;
  int b = 0, * pa = &a;

  ptrdiff_t ptr_diff = pa - &b;

  printf("pd = %td\n", ptr_diff);

  return 0;
}
```

---

Also the conversion specifier `"p"` is **only** defined for pointers to `void`. So the `printf()` calls shall look like:

```
      printf("The address of aPointer is %p \n", (void *) aPointer);
      printf("The address of bPointer is %p \n", (void *) bPointer);
```

---

Also^2 : The result of adding or substrating a value `v` from a pointer `p` is only a valid address if the result `pv` of the operation still refers to (an element/member of) the object the original pointer `p` pointed to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm even more confused about pointers as my book doesn't do much regarding printing pointers, this is something I'm trying to do extra to make more sense of them.  So what does `(void *)` actually mean?

Comment: @user1574598: `(void *) aPointer` tells the compiler to tread `aPointer` which is declared to be `int *` as if it where declared `void *` instead of `int *`. An `int *` typed variable is casted `void *`.

Comment: I see, well casting is something I'm not 100% with yet until I do some more reading.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

In your code aPointer is the value pointed by *aPointer. Same thing for bPointer.

As the comment says pointerSubtraction is the **value** obtained by the subtraction, not the address.